# fire a plugin after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wysiwyg

I have a text box that I am trying to turn into a wyiswyg (using [jwysiwyg](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg)). The textbox does not exist on the page until and ajax request is fired and it is loaded into the page via the request.

My problem is that I cannot get the textbox to become a wysiwyg with the normal

`$('.wysiwyg').wysiwyg();` as `.wysiwyg` does not exists on `DOM Ready` how can I work around this, I have tried the following,

```
$("a.suggest-date").click(function(){
        var self = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#mask").show();
        $("#suggestedDate").children().remove();
        $("#send-date textarea").val("");
        $.get(self + '#suggestedDate', null, function(result){ 
            $("#ajax-loaded").append(result);
            $(".wysiwyg").wysiwyg();
        });
        //$("#ajax-loaded").load(self + "#suggestedDate")
        $("#ajax-loaded").show();
        setTimeout(function() { $("#ajax-loaded").removeClass("loading"); $("#ajax-loaded header.loading").hide(); }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Answer (score 3):

```
$.get(self + '#suggestedDate').then(
    $(".wysiwyg").wysiwyg();
);
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

This will allow you to call .wysiwyg() once the your $.get call is successful.